# defu__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__ is not a function

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt-auth

Has anyone ever encountered this error when using nuxt-auth from [this](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/guide/setup/) official guide? How did you solve it? I'm stuck here for days.

The error is `defu__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__ is not a function`

Comment: Can you provide your code? Almost your package.json to check dependencies, your nuxt config or something we can check to help you

Answer (score 26):

I had the same issue today with a freshly installed **Nuxt 2.15.8** app. Once I added the **@nuxtjs/auth-next v.5.0.0-1667386184.dfbbb54** to go with **Laravel Sanctum** providers the app crashed with same error message. After alot of searching around I found a solution to make the app work again.

In **nuxt.config.js** add:

```
build: {
  transpile: [
    'defu'
  ]
}
```

Hope that **helps** for you and others having the same issue.

Comment: Big thanks for writing this here!

Answer (score 1):

Ran into a similar warning with `React` early this week, It means you are trying to call a function/access a property of a module that you imported but imported wrongly or it is not exported from the module. webpack throws that error: Similar problem was:

```
// inside get-user.js
const getUser = () => { 
  const result = localStorage.getItem('user')
  if(result) return JSON.parse(result)
  else return null
}
// Notice: missing export

// inside App.jsx
import getUser from './get-user'
const App = () => {
  const user = getUser()
}
```

As you can see, inside `get-user.js` it slipped my mind to add an `export` for the `getUser` function. Webpack bundles this but fails later on when I load the `App` component.
A possible cause for your issue:

1. Missing export for a reusable module you have written.
2. An issue with `next-auth` version you are using, Some libraries have breaking changes in a major release, for example, new versions of `node-fetch` is shipped as `ES6` module by default, suggestion is to switch to a lower version(stable) of the package.
3. Check your `export/imports` relating to that module in your code if they are correct.

Let me know if that helps,
Happy coding!